# Replace all columns with a specific prefix with a new column which will have values the numeric part of these columns

Tags: r

I have the data frame below in which I want to replace all the columns with `"VOT"` with one column named `"VOT"` which will include values  `(-60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20)`. The values that now exist in the columns after the `VOT`. Also I want to create a new column named response which will have the relative values `(0,1)`. It will be like (the vales of `VOT` are just divided by 1000):

```
data<-structure(list(Participant = c("Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", 
"Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", 
"Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", "Valentin", 
"Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", 
"Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", "Andres", 
"Andres", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", 
"Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", 
"Ivan", "Ivan", "Ivan", "Ivan", "Ivan"), Number = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Level = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1"
), `Time abroad` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `Spanish use` = c(42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 27, 27, 
27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
44), Block = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), `Place or articulation` = c("Bilabial", 
"Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Dental", "Dental", 
"Dental", "Dental", "Dental", "Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Velar", 
"Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", 
"Dental", "Dental", "Dental", "Dental", "Dental", "Velar", "Velar", 
"Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", 
"Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Dental", "Dental", "Dental", "Dental", 
"Dental", "Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Bilabial", 
"Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial"), `VOT 0` = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `VOT 5` = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    `VOT 10` = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `VOT 15` = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), `VOT 20` = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `VOT -10` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `VOT -20` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), `VOT -30` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), `VOT -40` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    `VOT -50` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `VOT -60` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Participant Level Place or articulation    VOT response
1    Valentin    A1              Bilabial  0.000        0
2    Valentin    A1              Bilabial  0.005        0
3    Valentin    A1              Bilabial  0.010        0
4    Valentin    A1              Bilabial  0.015        0
5    Valentin    A1              Bilabial  0.020        0
6    Valentin    A1              Bilabial -0.010        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` being your dataframe, you could try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with('VOT'),
               names_to = 'VOT',
               values_to = 'response'
               ) |>
  mutate(VOT = 1e-3 * (VOT |>
                gsub(pattern = '^VOT\\W*', replacement = '') |>
                as.numeric()
                )
         ) |>
  select(Participant, Level, `Place or articulation`, VOT:response)
```

```
# A tibble: 550 x 5
   Participant Level `Place or articulation`   VOT response
   <chr>       <chr> <chr>                   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0            0
 2 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.005        0
 3 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.01         0
 4 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.015        0
 5 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.02         0
 6 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.01         1
 7 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.02         1
 8 Valentin    A1    Bilabial                0.03         1
```